# migrating VS project from 2005 to 2008

Tags: visual-studio

I have a visual studio project that was originally built with Visual Studio 2005 Professional. It makes use of some features like crystal reports and building MSI files that are no available in the freely available Visual Studio 2008. I lost my 2005 license so I opted to download the free 2008 edition, and I migrated the project. Predictably, it tells me that certain parts of the project could not be migrated, but it does allow me to work with the other parts (which is totally fine with me). The problem is, because the migration "failed" it wants me to migrate the project every single time I try to open the project.

Can someone show me the break statement for this loop?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps [Don't sweat migrating legacy .NET projects to Visual Studio 2008](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/programming-and-development/dont-sweat-migrating-legacy-net-projects-to-visual-studio-2008/644)

[Here](http://www.emmet-gray.com/Articles/ProjectConverter.htm) is some information to try even doesn't help.

Make sure you open the converted project file.

Comment: Those are just links to walkthroughs for the conversion wizard. I already understand how to use the conversion wizard; it's just that the conversion wizard wants to convert my project each time I open it. This is because it is under the impression that the conversion failed (because there are elements to the project that are unconverted because they are not supported in the free version).

Comment: If you can open the project even though it's not fully successful, you could save the solution with VS2008. And next time it should open in VS2008 if you open the converted solution. If not, sorry I haven't come a cross such a situation.

Comment: Saving it doesn't help, it simply does not recognize it as a converted project.